# Getting started with akka persistence - Unable to replay messages

Tags: java, persistence, akka, akka-persistence

I am trying to write a very basic app where messages are sent to an actor at a higher rate, messages are being consumer by the actor at a slower rate, and then after some time, killing the app.
When I ran the app again with same actor system name and same actor name with same persistenceId, I was expecting to see the missed messages replayed, but it is not happening.

(If I delete the journal and snapshot locations, they are created again on the next run with some files which are not 0 byte sized, so something is happening for sure.)

**Edit1:** RecoveryCompleted object is being received in onReceiveRecover whenever I start the app.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("sample-actor-system");
        ActorRef sampleActor = actorSystem.actorOf(
                Props.create(AkkaWorker.class).withDispatcher(
                        "akka.actor.test-dispatcher"),
                "sample-actor");
        System.out.println(actorSystem.settings().config());
        int i = 1;
//Run this coe the next time so that nothing is published, and only the replayed messages should be executed by the actor
//        Thread.sleep(10000);
//        System.exit(0);
        while (true) {
            String msg = "Hello there" + i;
            sampleActor.tell(msg, null);
            System.out.println("Published message: " + msg);
            i++;
            // break;
            Thread.sleep(100);
            if (i == 20) {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}


public class AkkaWorker extends UntypedPersistentActor {

    public AkkaWorker() {

    }

    @Override
    public String persistenceId() {
        return "sample-id-1";
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveCommand(Object message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In onReceiveCommand");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (message instanceof String) {
            message = (String) message;
            System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
            if (((String) message).equalsIgnoreCase("suicide")) {
                System.out.println("killing self");
                getContext().stop(getSelf());
            }

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveRecover(Object message) {
        System.out.println("In onReceiveRecover");
        if (message instanceof String) {
            System.out.println(message);
        } else {
            System.out.println("God knows what: "+ message.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

In application.conf,

```
test-dispatcher {
      type = Dispatcher
      executor = "fork-join-executor"
      fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-min = 1
        parallelism-factor = 1.0
        parallelism-max = 1
      }
      throughput = 1
    }
persistence {
    journal {
      max-message-batch-size = 1
      leveldb {
        dir = "/Users/neeraj/akka-persist/journal"
        native = true
      }
    }
    snapshot-store.local.dir = "/Users/neeraj/akka-persist/snapshot"
  }
```

Comment: Akka Persistence is not a Durable Mailbox implementation. You first need to `persist` the messages that you want replayed on startup.

Comment: So I have to have an actor that calls the persist method for the incoming messages that I wish to perist? And that cannot be slow. And does the deletion of messages happen automatically or even that has to be done by deleteMessage call? If it has to be done explicitly, what is sequence number? (I am very new to akka world, and there is not much in the community)

Comment: You should read [Akka Persistence docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/persistence.html). All your questions are answered there.

Comment: I read the doc and a few discussions. Please verify if what I am saying is correct or not. 'persistent actors' are to store the current state/history of the state of an actor so that it can be used at a later point in time, primary purpose is NOT to queue messages in file system instead of RAM. If I want to use file system to q messages, I should store 'durable mailbox'. I see somebody suggesting that durable have a bad performance impact so we should move to persistent actors. So a persistent actor that takes care of persisting and deleting messages is a better choice than durable mailboxes?

Comment: My primary purpose is to queue messages in persistent store rather than in ram, so that if things go south, my RAM doesn't go full. And I might also put in some retry mechanism for things. (I probably want to use it as a queuing system, similar to, say, rabbitmq and its consumers)

Comment: Your journal (i.e. the class responsible for persisting the messages) is the one responsible of "how good" your storing mechanism is. You can code it to have batch, async read/writes to ease up your performance.

Comment: @neeraj in that case Persistent Actors might not be what you're looking for. Maybe a more classical MQ would be a better approach?

Comment: I was thinking the same. But assuming that for some reason I am still adamant on using akka, should I use durable mailboxes or should I use a persistent actor that persists the messages, sends them to its children, and children process the message and send a callback even to the parent, on which the parent deletes the message from the journal. (In the latter case, I may have to pass along the lastSequenceNr() to the child for it to return it back later, but some people say that messages should not be deleted one by one, since that is not the essence of event sourcing)